Semaphore implemented with signals not working
I am trying to write a semaphore using signals. code in main the checks that it works, it suppose to print (something like):
Thread 2 trying to enter critical section...
Thread 2 entered critical section.
Thread 1 trying to enter critical section...
Thread 2 leaving critical section.
Thread 1 entered critical section.
Thread 1 leaving critical section.

where every thread enters and leaves.
But it prints:
Thread 2 trying to enter critical section...
Thread 2 entered critical section.
Thread 1 trying to enter critical section...
Thread 2 leaving critical section.

and doesn't print that the other thread is also entering and leaving the critical section, also it doesn't terminate. My guess is that I don't understand how the sigsusppend() is working. Thank you in advance.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

// Global semaphore
volatile sig_atomic_t semaphore = 1;

// Signal handling function
void signal_handler(int sig) {
    semaphore = 1;  // Release the semaphore
}

// Initialize the semaphore
void sem_init() {
    struct sigaction sa;
    sa.sa_handler = signal_handler;
    sa.sa_flags = 0; // No flags
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL);

    // Block SIGUSR1 to prevent premature handling
    sigset_t set;
    sigemptyset(&set);
    sigaddset(&set, SIGUSR1);
    pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, NULL);
}

// Wait (down operation) on the semaphore
void sem_down() {
    sigset_t set;
    sigemptyset(&set);
    sigaddset(&set, SIGUSR1);
    while (!semaphore) {
        sigsuspend(&set); // Replace pause with sigsuspend for targeted waiting
    }
    semaphore = 0; // Take the semaphore
}

// Signal (up operation) on the semaphore
void sem_up() {
    semaphore = 1;
    kill(getpid(), SIGUSR1); // Send signal to release semaphore
}

// A simple thread function that uses the semaphore
void* thread_func(void* arg) {
    printf("Thread %ld trying to enter critical section...\n", (long)arg);
    sem_down();
    printf("Thread %ld entered critical section.\n", (long)arg);
    sleep(2); // Simulate critical section work
    sem_up();
    printf("Thread %ld leaving critical section.\n", (long)arg);
    return NULL;
}

// Main function to demonstrate semaphore usage
int main() {
    sem_init();

    pthread_t t1, t2;
    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, thread_func, (void*)1);
    pthread_create(&t2, NULL, thread_func, (void*)2);

    pthread_join(t1, NULL);
    pthread_join(t2, NULL);

    return 0;
}


Re "I am trying to write a semaphore using signals.", This is ultimately flawed because the number of times a signal handler is called can be less than the number of times the corresponding signal is raised.

You can get signals queued up if you use real time signals and a siginfo handler.

And Yet in this case, I can't see why I would want to queue the signals, there are only two threads that try to use the critical section.

There is a race condition on semaphore in sem_down().

The atomic type isn't suppose to prevent that?

after adding sleep between the two functions I think you are right. but can't make it to work or understand why this doesn't work. I would appreciate it if someone would expand or show me how to write it so it does work.

I would say that it's ultimately flawed not so much because of lack of signal queueing (though that is a potential issue), but because signal handling does not provide the memory semantics that semaphores do.  You may be able to make processes take turns by sending signals to each other, but it is misleading to call that an implementation of a semaphore.  And ever so much more so for making threads take turns, because the memory semantics are more likely to matter in this case.

Also, C's volatile is not useful for thread synchronization.

@ItaySegev, there are no race conditions involving objects of atomic type, but its name notwithstanding, sigatomic_t is not an atomic type.  Not in this sense, anyway.

Generalities
You cannot write a valid semaphore for synchronizing threads of the same process without either using other synchronization objects, such as C or pthreads mutexes, or using atomic objects and operations.  Its name notwithstanding, sigatomic_t is not atomic in this sense, and making it volatile does not help in that regard.
Appropriate atomic operations and operations on synchronization objects provide memory ordering semantics that are necessary for well-defined behavior in multithreaded programs that contain conflicting accesses to non-atomic shared data. Ironically, "non-atomic shared data" includes your semaphore variable.  Without appropriate synchronization, conflicting accesses constitute data races, and the behavior of a program execution containing a data race is undefined.  Your attempt at a semaphore therefore constitutes exactly the kind of source of UB that a semaphore should prevent.
A working semaphore using atomic objects
It looks like your idea for involving signals was that it would allow you to use sigsuspend() to avoid busy-waiting on the semaphore.  That's a laudable goal, but it's secondary to your semaphore actually working.  I advise you, then, to set aside all the signal handling while you attend to properly using an atomic object (maybe an _Atomic int) and appropriate atomic operations, certainly including atomic compare & exchange.  For example:
#include <stdatomic.h>

_Atomic int semaphore = ATOMIC_VAR_INIT(1);

// Wait (down operation) on the semaphore
void sem_down(void) {
    // Lower the semaphore, waiting as necessary for it first to be up
    int expected = 1;

    while (!atomic_compare_exchange_strong_explicit(&semaphore, &expected, 0,
            memory_order_acquire, memory_order_relaxed)) {
        // ... maybe suspend here ...
        expected = 1;
    }
}

// Signal (up operation) on the semaphore
void sem_up(void) {
    // Raise the semaphore.  Do not block, but do detect and warn if it is already raised
    int expected = 0;

    if (!atomic_compare_exchange_strong_explicit(&semaphore, &expected, 1,
            memory_order_release, memory_order_relaxed)) {
        fputs("warning: semaphore was already unlocked\n", stderr);
    }
    // ... maybe signal here ...
}

An atomic compare & exchange such as those in the above code modifies the value of the specified atomic object if and only if its original value is some specific expected one.  Atomically.  This is exactly what we want for lowering the semaphore if and only if it is currently raised, and it allows recognizing and warning about attempts to raise it when it is already raised.  The memory order specifications say that,

A thread that successfully lowers the semaphore will see the aggregate effects of all writes to shared variables preceding other threads' raisings of the semaphore.

A thread that fails to lower the semaphore (because it is already down) does not [need to] see any particular writes to non-atomic shared variables.

A thread that fails to raise the semaphore (because it is already up) does not [need to] see any particular writes to non-atomic shared variables.  This is not necessarily ideal, but it is necessary, and if it ever happens then that in itself already constitutes a bug.


Signals and avoiding busy-waiting
Suspending execution until signaled is nearly orthogonal to waiting for an object's value to change.  It can be done with sigsuspend(), but your implementation of that is incorrect.  Consider the notes from the Linux sigsuspend() manual page:

Normally, sigsuspend() is used in conjunction with sigprocmask(2)
in order to prevent delivery of a signal during the execution of
a critical code section.  The caller first blocks the signals
with sigprocmask(2).  When the critical code has completed, the
caller then waits for the signals by calling sigsuspend() with
the signal mask that was returned by sigprocmask(2) (in the
oldset argument).

You actually want to do the opposite: prevent signal delivery by default, but allow it under certain, narrow circumstances.  But that reversal is insignificant.  You can still follow the procedure described:

At the beginning of the program's execution

Ensure that SIGUSR1 is unblocked.
block SIGUSR1 before creating any additional threads.  Use pthread_sigmask() for this, as in your current code, but
when you do that, capture the original mask via the function's third argument, and store it somewhere appropiate.
register a do-nothing handler for the signal.  Even in your current code, it is not necessary for the handler to modify semaphore because your sem_up() already does that, but it should be clear here that this is for a wait / notification mechanism, not for the semaphore itself, so you don't want to muck with the semaphore value.


When a thread wants to suspend, it calls sigsuspend(), passing the stored original signal mask, which does not include SIGUSR1.  This allows the thread to receive SIGUSR1.
Your original code is flawed in this regard, as it blocks SIGUSR1 when it suspends (and unblocks all other signals), when it instead needs to unblock that signal.


I leave the details to you to implement, and to integrate into the semaphore to convert the busy wait into a non-busy one.  Although signals do have characteristics that make them problematic for some uses, I don't think that's an issue here:

because all threads not presently waiting on the signal keep it blocked, a signal that arrives when no threads are waiting will remain pending until one one waits

it doesn't matter if that wakes a thread from waiting early, because it will see that the semaphore is not actually available, and resume waiting

it doesn't matter that regular signals do not queue, because yours is a binary semaphore.  There is no use for multiple signals being pending at the same time because only one thread can acquire the semaphore, and it will signal when it releases it.

The use of sigsuspend() avoids issues with signals being received at an inopportune time, such as between testing the semaphore value and starting to wait.


